# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit hangs after boot

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 64-bit

I recently installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit version on my PC,
First I tried to install it from CD , but it hanged after minutes , then i tried it from a USB thumb drive the same problem ,

then I installed it using WUBI from windows 8 32-bit Pro it installed normally but whenever I boot , It hangs after two minutes, everything stops working but the mouse and the keyboard are working normally.

My PC specs are:

> MB : GigaByte G41
>
> CPU : Intel<sup>TM</sup> Core 2 Duo
>
> HDD : 320 GB WD
>
> GPU : Nvidia GT 630

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was the problem.

The generic drivers for the GPU was the problem , I had to download the correct driver from Nvidia, then install it using

`$ sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-319.23.run`

And install it with the GUI provided.